# Folder Named \ on Hard Drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I had a Hard Drive connected to my Raspberry Pi which runs Open Media Vault. Since I needed a faster access to it I disconnected it from the PI and connected it to my PC.

What I now discovered is, that the drive contains a folder called `\` (backslash).

If I open it, it just shows the same folders again and it seems just to redirect to the main directory of the drive.

If I open for the properties of this folder it actually just brings up the properties window of the hard drive itself.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this folder because if I try to delete it, it actually starts deleting all of the files on the Drive. Also renaming of the folder is not possible.

Comment: Type `chkdsk <driveletter>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect it back to the Raspberry Pi and delete the directory using `rmdir` from within Linux.

Comment: So you are sure that this will work on Linux? Because I am a bit afraid of loosing my data since deleting it on windows already caused some deleted files

Comment: Backslash is a path separator on Windows, but it's not special on Linux. You'd be deleting it the same way you created it – just a regular directory with a regular one-character name.